# Succeeding translateX - Why transition not animated

Tags: javascript, css-animations

The transition from translateX(100%) to translateX(0%)  is not animated. It seems like the "translateX(100%)" value is never adapted, but rather is "skipped".

```
 el.style.transitionDuration = null
 el.style.transform = "translateX(100%)"

 el.style.transitionDuration = "100ms"
 el.style.transform = "translateX(0%)"
```

But this one is working

```
 el.style.transitionDuration = null
 el.style.transform = "translateX(100%)"
 setTimeout(() => {
       el.style.transitionDuration = "100ms"
       el.style.transform = "translateX(0%)"
 }, 5)
```

Comment: That is not my problem, I am not looking for transitionend listener. I set transitionDuration to null and then translate the element without animation to a position, then I want it to translate back, but with transition animation. Second one is working, but first not

Comment: well, it better to assing a class with your transitions values

Comment: I am sorry, my question is rather, why the first translateX value seems to get skipped, because the element is not animating from translate 100 to translate 0. I have edited my question

Comment: Please make  Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help us help you. Its easy to make a HTML markup and you have SO fiddle to show us example. You will get your answer much quicker.